# Apache Mod-Rewrite rule to skip sub directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a application in the root directory of a website that has its own apache2 mod-rewrite rules e.g.

```
   RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?page=$1&var1=$2
   RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?page=$1
```

Thats fine but now I want to install Wordpress in a the subdirectory **/blog**. Wordpress of course has its own rewrite statements in the .htacess file that rewrites urls differently for the blog.

How can I tell the root .htaccess file to skip over the /blog/ directory and allow the local .htaccess mod-rewrite to still work when browsing int the blog directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just do a negation in your first htaccess like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/blog/.*$
```

this should do it - hopefully! as a precondition of the rules

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/ - [L]

RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ index.php?page=$1&var1=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: will this then not ignore the rules for wordpress in the blog dir?

Comment: No it won't because this ignore will be effective only in this current .htaccess